# how to write simultaneous subscript and superscript in y label legend with R

Tags: r, label

I want to write in y label for my plot(): 
NH4+-N **(subscript 4) (superscript +)** (mg L-1) **(superscript -1)**

can you help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `bquote`

```
 plot(1, ylab=bquote(NH[4]^"+"*N~mgL^-1))
```

Or as @MrFlick menioned, `quote` also works here.

```
 plot(1, ylab=quote(NH[4]^"+"*N~mgL^-1))
```

Comment: Since you're not using `.()` here, a standard `quote()` would work just as well.